# Is this correct, type and logic for matrices?

Tags: c, matrix, strcmp

I need put a 4 bytes and next 4 bytes in a matrix line. Example:

> verd verm azul amar bran pret null
>
> verd verm amar azul pret null bran
>
> amar verd amar azul null null bran
>
> ...

So the first position mastermind[0][0] returns "verd" and next mastermind[0][5] returns "verm"

```
int main(void){

    int i;
    char **mastermind;
    mastermind=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0; i<7; i++)
        mastermind[i]=(char *)malloc(36*sizeof(char));

    printf("Define Password: \n\tverd = 0 \n\tverm = 1 \n\tazul = 2 \n\tamar = 3 \n\trosa = 4 \n\tlila = 5\n");
    scanf("%s %s %s %s", &mastermind[0][0], &mastermind[0][5], &mastermind[0][10], &mastermind[0][15]);
    printf("\nPassword: %s %s %s %s\n", &mastermind[0][0], &mastermind[0][5], &mastermind[0][10], &mastermind[0][15]);
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%s %s %s %s", &mastermind[1][0], &mastermind[1][5], &mastermind[1][10], &mastermind[1][15]);
return 0;
}
```

The problem is I'm using '&' for access and in some functions like strcmp I can't use, so I'm missing something.

Is this the right way?

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char *))` - how much memory do you think this is allocating?

Comment: Inasmuch as you do not test that the `scanf()` calls succeed, it is not correct.  Inasmuch as you allocate enough space for one `char *` for `mastermind` and then proceed to use it as an array of 7 elements, then: **No** it is very incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

These lines:

```
int i;
char **mastermind;
mastermind=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    mastermind[i]=(char *)malloc(36*sizeof(char));
```

will lead to undefined behavior since you are allocating space for one pointer  but are using it as an array of 7 pointers.

Change the line:

```
mastermind=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

to

```
mastermind=malloc(sizeof(char *)*7);
```

Still better, use:

```
mastermind=malloc(sizeof(*matermind)*7);
```

**Update**

Since you know the sizes of arrays, you can avoid use of `malloc` altogether by using:

```
char mastermind[7][36];
```

Comment: But if I not user a array of 8 pointers to pointers I can't access the elements easily later like I'm doing.

Comment: @LuizMeirelles: Increase the initial `malloc()` to `mastermind = (char **)malloc(7 * sizeof(*mastermind));` or equivalent, or add more space if you prefer.